# Use variable for Bitbucket custom pipeline deployment value

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to set the deployment variable for a step using a variable that is passed to a custom pipeline. The idea is not to have to duplicate the custom pipeline as the only change is the deployment variables that are read from bitbucket settings.

The definition looks as follows, but throws an error

```
pipelines:
  custom:
    my-pipeline:
       - variables:   
          - name: deployment
       - step: 
           deployment: $deployment 
           script:
             - ...
```

Am I missing something here, or is the deployment key not allows to accept a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunetly you can't use variables in the `deployment` field. Variables are only available in `script` fiels. However, your problem is easily solved in another way: [anchors](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/)

For example:

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &Test-step
        name: Run tests
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run test
    - step: &Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to staging
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build
          - fab deploy
pipelines:
  default:
    - step: *Test-step
    - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to Staging
        deployment: staging
        trigger: manual
  custom:
    Staging Deployment
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          deployment: staging
    Production Deployment
      - step: *Test-step
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          deployment: production
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question was specifically if variables can be used as input for DEPLOYMENT variable, the answer has also been confirmed as NO by Atlassian. Your example doesn't solve my use case. As it stands right now, the answer is that you cannot use variables for the deployment key.