# Bitbucket Pipeline deployment clause does not support a variable

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to set the deployment based on the $BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH which is set using

```
if [[ "$BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
    export ENV_NAME=prd
elif [[ "$BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH" == "uat" ]]; then
    export ENV_NAME=uat
...
```

which is defined in `*set-deployment-environment`

however bitbucket-pipeline does not support `deployment: $ENV_NAME`

```
  pull-requests:
    release/*:
      - step: *set-deployment-environment
      - step: 
          <<: *ansible-build-deploy
          name: Deploying to environment
          deployment: $ENV_NAME
```

Looking at the response here, [Use variable for Bitbucket custom pipeline deployment value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488916/use-variable-for-bitbucket-custom-pipeline-deployment-value). Can anyone suggest a solution, without duplicating chunk of code just to have two lines different, i.e.

`deployment: uat`

or

`deployment: prd`

Comment: So, you want the deployment to happen when a PR is opened instead of when a PR is merged? Is that right?

Comment: After it is merged from the release/* into the destination branch, uat or master. I want the deployment field to update with the correct environment. However the deployment field does not take a variable. Looking for a clean solution with the gap in the bitbucket-pipeline design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the deployment to happen when a PR is merged on a particular target branch, which is the most common approach, just use branch pipelines instead of pull-request pipelines!

```yaml
pipelines:
  default: # ...
  custom: # ...
  pull-requests: # maybe run some tests? ...
  branches:
    master:
      - step: 
          <<: *ansible-build-deploy
          name: Deploying to environment
          deployment: prd
    uat:
      - step: 
          <<: *ansible-build-deploy
          name: Deploying to environment
          deployment: uat
```